# Cannot retrieve Values from HTML form For PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

OK so i need to retrieve my variables from the form and put them in an insert statement so
i can enter them to a database. the issue seems to be in the from where i retrieve them as
if i hardcode them in the form it works, so there is no issue with the database or the connection, only with retrieving price and isbn as shown below.

```
 <?php session_start();
 session_regenerate_id();
 ($_SESSION['count']) ? $_SESSION['count']++ : $_SESSION['count'] = 1;



?>

<!-- example for PHP 5.0.0 final release -->

<html>

 <head>
  <title>Session running</title>
 </head>

 <body>
 <h1> Book Details</h1>
 <a href="catalog.php?<?php echo( SID ); ?>">Go Back To Inventory</a>
 <hr>
 PHPSESSID = <?php echo session_id(); ?>
 <br>
 You have been here <?php echo( $_SESSION['count'] ); ?> times in this session
 <hr>


<html>
<head>
<title>Count Visits</title>
</head>

<body>
<h2></h2>

</body>
</html>



<?php require_once("Include/db_connect.php");

if (isset($_REQUEST['button'])) // submit was clicked
{

display_output_page();
}

?>
<?php






    $db_link = db_connect("project");



    $self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) // submit was clicked
{

      display_output_page();
   }


?>









<?php


    $isbn = $_REQUEST['isbn'];
    $price = isset($_REQUEST['price']) ? $_REQUEST['price'] : '';
    $quantity = isset($_REQUEST['value']) ? $_REQUEST['value'] : '';












$fields = mysql_list_fields("project", "books");
$num_columns = mysql_num_fields($fields);


$query = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE isbn=".$isbn.";";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("SQL failed");




echo '<table border="1">';



echo "<tr>";
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_columns; $i++)
{
   echo "<th>", mysql_field_name($fields, $i), "</th>";


}
  echo "<th> Quantity </th>";
    echo "<th> Add </th>";
echo "</tr>";


while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{



        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['isbn']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['title']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['author']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['pub']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['year']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['price']."</td>";
        echo "<td><img src='images/".$row['image']."'></td>";


//IN HERE IS THE PROBLEM, RETRIEVING THE isbn and price variables wont work



        echo '<form action="" method="POST">
    <td><input type = "text" value=1 style="width: 30px;" name =   "value"/></td>
    <input type="hidden" name="isbn"  value="<php echo $isbn ?>">
    input type="hidden" name="price"  value="<?php echo $price ?>">
    <td><input type = "submit" name = "button" value = "Add"></td>

                </form>

    ';



        echo "</tr>";








}
echo "</table>";





mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close($db_link);
?>


<?php
function display_output_page()
{


 require_once("Include/db_connect.php");
 $db_link = db_connect("project");


//This is where i need to retrieve the isbn and price variables for my SQL insert

    $sessionID = session_id();
    $isbn = $_REQUEST['isbn'];
    $price = $_REQUEST['price'];
    $quantity =$_REQUEST['value'];


 $db_link = db_connect("project");
 $sql2 = "INSERT INTO cart(sessionID,isbn,quantity,price)
 VALUES('$sessionID','$isbn','$quantity','$price')";


 $result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die ("<br> Could not execute SQL query");

 if($result2)
{

echo "You Have Added The Item To The Cart";

}


mysql_close($db_link);

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some basic syntax elements.

```
<input type="hidden" name="isbn"  value="<?php echo $isbn; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="price"  value="<?php echo $price; ?>">
```

Also I suggest that you read this about basis PHP HTML form handling, because there are a lot of small mistakes in your code.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: Yes I have only begun studying PHP and HTML , I tried your above code but It still won't pass the values.. Thanks for your reply though!

Comment: Please do not recommend w3schools as a resource. There are many problems with it, as outlined on http://www.w3fools.com/.